# Copy all script arguments to another variable

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I need to copy all script arguments and pass them to another script. I have tried to do it like this:

```
args=$@    
printargs.sh $args
echo ------
printargs.sh "$args"
```

but in such case if i call my parent script with arguments containing spaces e.g.:

```
script.sh "arg 1" "arg 2"
```

then it prints

```
arg
1
arg
2
----
arg 1 arg 2
```

How should I do this in bash or alternatively to be compatible with POSIX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$@` is like an array, so your temporary storage needs to be an array:

```
args=( "$@" )      # quotes are needed there
```

And then to use them:

```
printargs.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Note that arrays are not part of the POSIX standard -- they work in bash and zsh, but not all other POSIX-compatible shells.